# Gnuradio: Getting the output value of a block

Tags: python, gnuradio, gnuradio-companion

I would like to obtain the value heading out of a block. For example what the value at the output of a multiply block which combines two sine functions. Or accessing and working with the output of a square wave.

something along the lines of

```
def get_multply_output(self):
    return self.blocks_multiply_xx_0.output_items[0]
```

is there a way i can access the output value each time it is updated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the ["Probe Signal" `gr::blocks::probe_signal`](https://www.gnuradio.org/doc/doxygen/classgr_1_1blocks_1_1probe__signal.html) block to your flow graph. Its `level()` method returns the item it most recently received on its input.

There are also other blocks named `probe_*` to provide other measurements such as item throughput; their commonality is that you have to poll them (ask them for their current value) rather than them producing items or messages.